# Include html from remote server Edit then save on remote server

Tags: php, html, ftp, include, edit

*Let me begin with, that English is not my native tong.
There probably gonna be some miss-pelt words/sentences.*

**Explaining the situation:**

I have bought a script for a lot of money that allows me to put it in the root directory and edit the static html documents with specific tags.
It saves the changes direct on the html.
i use it for old clients that bought a website from me a wile ago. (static html css websites)

Now i dont want to put the script on their own webserver, i would practically be giving away a script where somebody put a lot of time in.

**The plan**

Now i plan to put it on my own server next to my website.
The script allows me to save through a ftp connection.
so its save to say that it is possible to save from a remote server.
I manage to make a simple user script that let the client log in than php gets the ftp information from my sql server for the "ftp save function".

**But now the real question**

Is it possible for me to let my clients login onto my webserver and then "Include" their website into the session on my server and let the editor do his thing ?

so the script has to thing that it is on the root of the html document.

My explaining is probably unclear so let me add a image ;)

[picaso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Nh8.jpg)

Thank you for your time .. 
Hope to hear something from you all.

Comment: what does including their website into your session even mean? I don't think that's a thing.

Comment: This is once more the old question about how to protect the "intellectual property" of a simple script towards clients. Simple answer is: the effort you make for all of this by far exceeds any sense. A simple script is nothing worth to be protected by such means. In the end you only annoy your customers, frustrate yourself and you have gained nothing, since your customers won't pirate your script anyway.